# Convert from mbus protocol to modbusIP

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, modbus, smbus

Im trying to convert mbus protocol to modbus IP protocol with a raspberry.

Im new on this, just doing bcs my boss asked. I´ve been searching on all google, but I found nothing. Any help would be helpful.

I´ve tried to read mbus bytes to convert, but it´s impossible.

Comment: How did you connect a mbus slave to your rpi? Are you using http://www.ti.com/product/TSS721A?

Comment: With serial port @Bosz

Answer (score 0):

Both protocols seem to be completely different.

So if you want to convert, you will have to create a dedicated library. A huge pile of work. And, on top of that, I am not really sure that you can represent the same data in both protocols, as they have different goals.

But maybe you want to *encapsulate* MBus in Modbus, in order to travel on Modbus, and at the other end extract it to decode MBus where needed.

I think we need more info on your exact goal here.

Anyway, MBus protocol is described in standard EN13757 that you will need to get if you plan to decode this protocol.

[I have been creating a library decoding MBus protocol, but it is not open-source nor publicly available. If you need furher help with MBus protocol, you can contact me.]